# React Material UI dropdown menu position changed during zoom out

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**In React Material UI v4 or v5**, there is a common problem with zoom out, for example, if you put the following style to body or HTML tag:

```
    body {
    zoom: 80%; /* Zoom out */
    }
```

all the dropdowns in the **Material UI position** will be shifted from the correct place that must be on it.

**1: This is the correct place without zoom:**

[image]

**2: This is the issue after adding zoom:**

[image]

**3: This is the video for the problem:**

[Dropdown menu video Mui v4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sHMO_eCjlE)

**4: Some notes about this issue:**

1- Actually, we can fix the problem using browser zoom out by pressing command and [ - ] key, but I'm looking for a code-based solution without telling the users to do something.

2- [Select2](https://select2.org/) not facing the same issue, you can zoom out and keep the menu in the same place, maybe that because the way of implementing the dropdown is different.

[Sandbox link for Select2](https://t0wpp.csb.app/)

3- [Angular](https://t0wpp.csb.app/) Material not facing the same issue you can follow the link for the sandbox [Angular](https://t0wpp.csb.app/) to make sure there is no issue with zoom out.

***5: The question is how to make Material UI behaves like Select2/ Angular Material or the normal dropdown
without telling users to do something, How does Material UI determine the dropdown menu position? how we can override this function?***

Comment: Can you share the css for the dropdown boxes themselves, it might happen because the dropdowns are set as absolute elements

Comment: @devAgam there is a CSS for that, what I'm looking for is the function that determines the position of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the zoom value in dropdown list to 80% too so that it matches the <body> tag.

Code sample:

```
  <FormControl fullWidth>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={age}
      label="Age"
      onChange={handleChange}
      MenuProps={{ sx: { zoom: "80%" } }}
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```